# I am getting 6 errors, it looks like all of them are in IEnumerators

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

[image: 6 errors]
Here are the errors.

I am creating a firebase login and sign up unity project.

I have commented some of the lines because I havent programmed it yet. I am following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-ZS7-I_CfQ

I have 2 scripts, firebaseManager and authUI manager.

Here is my firebaseManager script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;
using TMPro;


public class FirebaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static FirebaseManager instance;

[Header("Firebase")]
public FirebaseAuth auth;
public FirebaseUser user;
[Space(5f)]

[Header("Login References")]
[SerializeField]
private TMP_InputField loginEmail;
[SerializeField]
private TMP_InputField loginPassword;
[SerializeField]
private TMP_Text loginOutputText;
[Space(5f)]

[Header("Register References")]
[SerializeField]
private TMP_InputField registerUsername;
[SerializeField]
private TMP_InputField registerEmail;
[SerializeField]
private TMP_InputField registerPassword;
[SerializeField]
private TMP_InputField registerConfirmPassword;
[SerializeField]
private TMP_Text registerOutputText;

private void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    else if (instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(instance.gameObject);
        instance = this;
    }

}

private void Start() 
{
    StartCoroutine(CheckAndFixDependancies());
}

private IEnumerator CheckAndFixDependancies()
{
    var checkAndFixDependanciesTask = FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync();

    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => checkAndFixDependanciesTask.IsCompleted);

    var dependancyResult = checkAndFixDependanciesTask.Result;
    
    if (dependancyResult == DependencyStatus.Available)
    {
        InitializeFirebase();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Could not resolve all firebase dependancies: {dependancyResult}");
    }
}

private void InitializeFirebase()
{
    auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    StartCoroutine(CheckAutoLogin());

    auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
    AuthStateChanged(this, null);
}

private IEnumerator CheckAutoLogin()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    if (user != null)
    {
        var reloadUserTask = user.ReloadAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => reloadUserTask.IsCompleted);

        AutoLogin();
    }
    else
    {
        AuthUIManager.instance.LoginScreen();
    }
}

private void AutoLogin()
{
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (user.IsEmailVerified)
        {
            GameManager.instance.ChangeScene(1);
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(SendVerificationEmail());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        AuthUIManager.instance.LoginScreen();
    }
}

private void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (auth.CurrentUser != user)
    {
        bool signedIn = user != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;

        if (!signedIn && user != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Signed Out");
            // Write signed out user code here
        }

        user = auth.CurrentUser;

        if (signedIn)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Signed In: {user.DisplayName}");
        }
    }
}

public void ClearOutputs()
{
    loginOutputText.text = "";
    registerOutputText.text = "";
}

public void LoginButton()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoginLogic(loginEmail.text, loginPassword.text));
}

public void RegisterButton()
{
    StartCoroutine(RegisterLogic(registerUsername.text, registerEmail.text, registerPassword.text, registerConfirmPassword.text));
}

private IEnumerator LoginLogic(string _email, string _password)
{
    Credential credential = EmailAuthProvider.GetCredential(_email, _password);

    var loginTask = auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential);
    
    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => loginTask.IsCompleted);

    if (loginTask.Exception != null)
    {
        FirebaseException firebaseException = (FirebaseException)loginTask.Exception.GetBaseException();

        AuthError error = (AuthError)firebaseException.ErrorCode;

        string output = "Unknown Error, Please Try Again";

        switch (error)
        {
            case AuthError.MissingEmail:
                output = "Please Enter Your Email";
                break;
            case AuthError.MissingPassword:
                output = "Please Enter Your Password";
                break;
            case AuthError.InvalidEmail:
                output = "Invalid Email";
                break;
            case AuthError.WrongPassword:
                output = "Incorrect Password";
                break;
            case AuthError.UserNotFound:
                output = "Account Does Not Exist";
                break;
        }
        loginOutputText.text = output;
    }
    else
    {
        if (user.IsEmailVerified)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

            GameManager.instance.ChangeScene(1);
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(SendVerificationEmail());
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator RegisterLogic(string _username, string _email, string _password, string _confirmPassword)
{
    if (_username == "")
    {
        registerOutputText.text = "Please Enter A Username";
    }
    else if (_password != _confirmPassword)
    {
        registerOutputText.text = "Passwords Do Not Match!";
    }
    // else if (_username.ToLower() == "bad word")
    // {
    //     registerOutputText.text = "That Username Is Innapropriate";
    // }
    else
    {
        var registerTask = auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(_email, _password);

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => registerTask.IsCompleted);

        if (registerTask.Exception != null)
        {
            FirebaseException firebaseException = (FirebaseException)registerTask.Exception.GetBaseException();

            AuthError error = (AuthError)firebaseException.ErrorCode;

            string output = "Unknown Error, Please Try Again";

            switch (error)
            {
                case AuthError.InvalidEmail:
                    output = "Invalid Email";
                    break;
                case AuthError.EmailAlreadyInUse:
                    output = "Email Is Already In Use";
                    break;
                case AuthError.WeakPassword:
                    output = "Weak Password. Please include capital letters, numbers and special symbols.";
                    break;
                case AuthError.MissingEmail:
                    output = "Please Enter Your Email";
                    break;
                case AuthError.MissingPassword:
                    output = "Please Enter Your Password";
                    break;
            }
            registerOutputText.text = output;
        }
        else
        {
            UserProfile profile = new UserProfile
            {
                DisplayName = _username,

                PhotoUrl = new System.Uri("https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/29/75/83/360_F_229758328_7x8jwCwjtBMmC6rgFzLFhZoEpLobB6L8.jpg");
            };

            var defaultUserTask = user.UpdateUserProfileAsync(profile);

            yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => defaultUserTask.IsCompleted);

            if (defaultUserTask.Exception != null)
            {
                user.DeleteAsync();

                FirebaseException firebaseException = (FirebaseException)defaultUserTask.Exception.GetBaseException();

                AuthError error = (AuthError)firebaseException.ErrorCode;

                string output = "Unknown Error, Please Try Again";

                switch (error)
                {
                    case AuthError.Cancelled:
                        output = "Update User Cancelled";
                        break;
                    case AuthError.SessionExpired:
                        output = "Session Expired";
                        break;
                }
                registerOutputText.text = output;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log($"Firebase User Created Successfuly: {user.DisplayName} ({user.UserId})");

                StartCoroutine(SendVerificationEmail());
            }
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator SendVerificationEmail()
{
    if (user != null)
    {
        var emailTask = user.SendEmailVerificationAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => emailTask.IsCompleted);

        if (emailTask.Exception != null)
        {
            FirebaseException firebaseException = (FirebaseException)emailTask.Exception.GetBaseException();
            AuthError error = (AuthError)firebaseException.ErrorCode;

            string output = "Unkown Error, Try Again!";

            switch (error)
            {
                case AuthError.Cancelled:
                    output = "Verification Task Was Cancelled";
                    break;
                case AuthError.InvalidRecipientEmail:
                    output = "Invalid Email";
                    break;
                case AuthError.TooManyRequests:
                    output = "Too Many Requests";
                    break;
            }

            AuthUIManager.instance.AwaitVerification(false, user.Email, output);
        }
        else
        {
            AuthUIManager.instance.AwaitVerification(true, user.Email, null);
            Debug.Log("Email Sent Successfully");
        }
    }
}

public void UpdateProfilePicture(string _newPfpURL)
{
    StartCoroutine(UpdateProfilePictureLogic(_newPfpURL));
}

private IEnumerator UpdateProfilePictureLogic(string _newPfpURL)
{
    if (user != null)
    {
        UserProfile profile = new UserProfile();

        try
        {
            UserProfile _profile = new UserProfile
            {
                PhotoUrl = new System.Uri(_newPfpURL),
            };

            profile = _profile;
        }
        catch
        {
            // LobbyManager.instance.Output("Error Fetching Image, Make Sure Your Link Is Valid!");
            yield break;
        }

        var pfpTask = user.UpdateProfileAsync(profile);
        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => pfpTask.IsCompleted);

        if (pfpTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Updating Profile Picture was unsuccessful: {pfpTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            LobbyManager.instance.ChangePfpSuccess();
            Debug.Log("Profile Image Updated Successfully");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my AuthUIManager script:

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class AuthUIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static AuthUIManager instance;

[Header("References")]
[SerializeField]
private GameObject checkingForAccountUI;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject loginUI;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject registerUI;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject verifyEmailUI;
[SerializeField]
private TMP_Text verifyEmailText;

private void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    else if (instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

private void ClearUI()
{
    loginUI.SetActive(false);
    registerUI.SetActive(false);
    verifyEmailUI.SetActive(false);
    FirebaseManager.instance.ClearOutputs();
    checkingForAccountUI.SetActive(false);
}

public void LoginScreen()
{
    ClearUI();
    loginUI.SetActive(true);
}

public void RegisterScreen()
{
    ClearUI();
    registerUI.SetActive(true);
}

public void AwaitVerification(bool _emailSent, string _email, string _output)
{
    ClearUI();
    verifyEmailUI.SetActive(true);
    if (_emailSent)
    {
        verifyEmailText.text = $"Sent Email!\nPleaseVerify {_email}";
    }
    else
    {
        verifyEmailText.text = $"Email Not Sent: {_output}\nPlease Verify {_email}";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is a typo. If you aren't bothered to read your own code why do you think other people would want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `FirebaseManager` script you've put a semicolon `;` at the end of line 264 instead of a comma `,`.

Additionally you've put a desperate closed curly bracket `}` at the end of the file, which is not necessary.

All other errors basically originate from these two problems.